# How to create sub types in Astro content collections

Tags: astrojs

I have a content collection in AstroJs which has a property as an object.
How can i create a Type for this object and reuse it in a component?

The schema:

```
const blog = defineCollection({
  schema: ({ image }) =>
    z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      description: z.string(),
      publishDate: z.date(),
      observations: z
        .array(
          z.object({
            title: z.string(),
            img: image(),
            body: z.string(),
          })
        )
        .optional(),
      heroImage: image().optional(),
    }),
});
```

The element in the observations should become a Type so that i can reference it in a props Type later:
F.e.:

```
<Cards observations={frontmatter.observations} />
```

Desired props definition:

```
export interface Props {
  observations: Observation[];
}
```

I tried with references as described here: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#defining-collection-references.

But this requires to store the object in seperate files resp. collection.
I would like to have them in the frontmatter of the mdx file directly, like so:

```
---
title: "title"
description: "some desc."
publishDate: 2022-05-23
observations:
  - title: "title 1"
    img: "../../assets/img1.jpg"
    body: "text"
  - title: "title 2"
    img: "../../assets/img2.jpg"
    body: "text"
---
```

So how can i have a Type for this nested "observation" element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Astro is using [Zod](https://zod.dev/) for this, you can do:

```
import { defineCollection, z, type ImageFunction } from "astro:content";

const getObservationSchema = (image: ImageFunction) =>
  z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    img: image(),
    body: z.string(),
  })

const blog = defineCollection({
  schema: ({ image }) =>
    z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      description: z.string(),
      publishDate: z.date(),
      observations: z.array(getObservationSchema(image)).optional(),
      heroImage: image().optional(),
    }),
});

export type Observation = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof getObservationSchema>>
```

Comment: Thanks, `z.infer<typeof observationSchema>` was the missing piece.
But now the image() helper is outside of defineCollection and therefore undefined.
Any Idea?

Comment: oh right, I edited my answer to fix that...